# Which version of Spatialite does QGIS support?

Tags: qgis, spatialite

At work, we utilize QGIS 2.8.3. I am interested in some features of SpatiaLite, as **styling support** *(since version 4.3.0)* and **topology support** *(since 4.4.0, a Release Candidate version)*.

Where can I found which version of SpatiaLite a specific version of QGIS supports?

Comment: In qgis  Help->about  ,you have the SpatialLite version.

Comment: Thank you, @FranciscoRaga! Post it as a answer, so I can close the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In qgis Help->about ,you have the SpatialLite version.

[image]